# Having difficulty proving the following set is a semi-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $d\in\mathbb{N}$
  define: $$\mathcal{R}_{0}^{d}=\left\{ \emptyset\right\} \cup\left\{ \left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\times...\times\left(a_{d},b_{d}\right]\,|\,-\infty\leq a_{j}\leq b_{j}\leq\infty\,\forall\,1\leq j\leq d\right\} \subseteq\mathcal{P}\left(\mathbb{R}^{d}\right)$$
 When for $b_{i}=\infty$
  we mean $\left(a_{i},b_{i}\right]=\left(a_{i},\infty\right)$
 . I'm attempting to show that for $d=2$
  this is a semi-algebra (which is also true for general $d$
 ). My problem is showing that given two sets $\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\times\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right]$
 and  $\left(c_{1},d_{1}\right]\times\left(c_{2},d_{2}\right]$
  in $\mathcal{R}_{0}^{2}$
  the difference $$\left(\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right]\times\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right]\right)\backslash\left(\left(c_{1},d_{1}\right]\times\left(c_{2},d_{2}\right]\right)$$
  can be represented as a finite union of sets in $\mathcal{R}_{0}^{2}$.

Help would definitely be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that if $X$ and $Y$ are two sets, and $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$, then 
$$(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)=(X\times B^c)\cup (A^c\times Y).$$
We thus have 
$$((a_1,b_1]\times  (a_2,b_2])\setminus ((c_1,d_1]\times (c_2,d_2])=\left[((a_1,b_1]\times  (a_2,b_2])\cap (\mathbb R\times (c_2,d_2]^c)\right]\cup\left[((a_1,b_1]\times  (a_2,b_2])\cap (c_1,d_1]^c\times \mathbb R)\right].$$
Now the conclusion follows from the case $d=1$.

Comment: Takes a few good more steps of set algebra to reach the desired result but it indeed works. Thanks.